# When i minimize chrome window, selenium stops

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I use selenium and python to send message. **And the process can run correctly when the chrome window is on screen**. But after I minimize the chrome window, the error will occur. And sending message failed.(when execute js to send words to TextArea)

> [13988:1284:0501/110015.734:ERROR:latency_info.cc(164)] Display::DrawAndSwap, 
>   LatencyInfo vector size 102 is too big.

I can't find enough error info about "Display::DrawAndSwap" in website. And as for the "size is too big", many answer exist. I have tried to use chunk and execute_script() to avoid send too many words, but failed.

My last question about

> error:element is not clickable at the point, other element will receive the click

can be solved by execte_script (It occurs too after I minimize the window). But this error can't be solved like this.

The problem Looks like the GPU can't draw the chrome when it's minimized. How should I do to avoid the error?(I don't want to open chrome headless, and want to minimize it sometimes)

And I run it on the remote desktop (windows server 2012,RAM 1.7GB),does it matter?

Comment: I run the process on my local PC correctly while minimized. But I want to make it run on remote desktop.

Comment: after I minimize the chrome window, how did you do this part ?

Comment: click the button "-" on the title bar

Comment: Don't minimize just open any other application you want to work. It automatically run without active window.